# Accesing values on a 2d struct array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

So I have this struct

```
struct cell
{
    int downwall;
    int rightwall;
};
```

I have dynamically allocated memory for a 2d array of struct cell
(struct cell ** array)

However when I try to access a certain cell with the command

```
array[i][j] -> downwall = 0;
```

I get this error:

> invalid type argument of '->' (have 'struct cell')

Comment: `struct cell ** array` is **not** a 2D array! A pointer is not an array. Use a correct 2D array instead. Reading a good C book about arrays, pointers and `struct` might be a good idea. The error message is quite clear.

Comment: Using double star in the pointer declaration seems to be the primary problem. You should either use `struct cell *array = malloc(m * n * sizeof(struct cell))` or better use `struct cell array[m][n]`. Then, you can use `(array + i * n + j)->downwall` or `a[i][j].downwall`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
array[i][j].downwall = 0;
```

instead.

You would have used `->` if `arrray[i][j]` had type `struct cell*` which it doesn't have. It has type `struct cell`.

Answer (score 1):

The type of `array[i][j]` will be of `struct cell`, not `struct cell *`. You should use the `.` operator to access a member.

You need to write

```
 array[i][j].downwall = 0;   // use of .
```

Answer (score 0):

Please note that

```
struct cell** array
```

is not a 2D array! it is a pointer to a pointer of type 'struct cell'.
You should regard it as a 2D array only if there is an allocated memory to which the values point (Statically or dynamically). Otherwise, you are on the road for a Segmentation Faults.

Answer (score 0):

Your struct is not a pointer struct so simply do something like:

```
//array cells of type cell and can hold 10 cell's
struct cell cells[10];

//Try using malloc for memory allocation
 cells[0] = (struct cell *) malloc(sizeof(struct cell));  

//example assignment
cells[0].downwall=0;
cells[0].rightwall=1;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to declare an actual array with the right number of indices, then make the pointer point to it.  Use typed names to help ( simplified Hungarian Notation )

```
 int    iAry[M][N];
 int    **ptrAry;

 ptrAry = iAry;    /*  equivalent to ptrAry = &iAry[0][0];    */

 /* then use -> operator as you have done   */
```